# Why my strategy doss not execute in tradingview? it creates no trade? caution! this strategy did not generate any orders throughout the testing range

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, execute, strategy-pattern, entry-point

`//@version=5 strategy("4:4 S1", overlay=true) // Indicator Inputs fairValueGap = input(0.5, "Lux Algo Fair Value Gap") cciLevel = input(100, "CCI Level") cci = ta.cci(close, 20) regressionLength = input(20, "Regression Length") supertrendLength = input(10, "Supertrend Length") stopLoss = input(4, "Stop Loss (pips)") takeProfit = input(4, "Take Profit (pips)") // Calculate Indicators fairValue = ta.sma(close, 20) + fairValueGap supertrendUp = ta.sma(high, supertrendLength) + fairValueGap supertrendDown = ta.sma(low, supertrendLength) - fairValueGap regressionMA = ta.linreg(close, regressionLength, 0) // Define Long Entry Condition longEntry = close > (fairValue) and close > supertrendUp and (regressionMA) > 0 and ta.cci(close, 20) > -100 and ta.cci(close, 20) < 100 // Define Short Entry Condition shortEntry = close < (fairValue) and close < (supertrendDown) and (regressionMA) < 0 and ta.cci(close, 20) > -100 and ta.cci(close, 20) < 100 // Execute Trades if longEntry strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long) if shortEntry strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short) // Set Stop Loss and Take Profit stopLossPips = ta.valuewhen(longEntry, close, 0) - stopLoss * syminfo.mintick takeProfitPips = ta.valuewhen(longEntry, close, 0) + takeProfit * syminfo.mintick strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Take Profit", "Long", stop=stopLossPips, limit=takeProfitPips) strategy.exit("Stop Loss/Take Profit", "Short", stop=stopLossPips, limit=takeProfitPips) plotshape(longEntry, location=location.belowbar, size=size.normal, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup) plotshape(shortEntry, location=location.abovebar, size=size.normal, color=color.red, style=shape.triangledown)``

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take the time to edit your question to format your code, and provide more details.   Please include whatever error you get.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I made the strategy and applied it to tradingview strategy tester but it doesnt work. I want to know why?

Answer (score 0):

When I apply your strategy to a chart, it executes thousands of trades, so there doesn't seem to be any issue with the entry criteria.

What usually prevents the strategy from entering trades is your position sizing settings. For some instruments, TradingView's broker emulator would not fill an order unless you bought at least one contract.

To ensure that your strategy always buys at least one contract, set the `Order Size` to `1 Contract`:

[image: Order size settings]

Comment: thanks bro, but it still doesnt work. I made changes exactly as the picture.

Comment: Please provide a link to a shared chart on which you have the script applied, and I will take a look.

Comment: this is the link of the chart with my strategy: thanks a lot :) 
     https://www.tradingview.com/chart/GBPUSD/UAHc5JBg-Strategy-scalp-1/

Comment: The "fair value gap" is too high for the entry criteria to ever become true on `GBPUSD`. Try changing the fair value gap to `0.001`.